# java.lang.NullPointerException on non-null android view

Tags: java, android, kotlin, asynchronous, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to enter some api results into a layout in android studio, but I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` on the view when it's not. Here is my code:

```
AsyncTask.execute {
    var related = gson.fromJson(AnibaseApi().getAnimeRelated(anime.id), Array<AnimeResponseObject>::class.java)

    println(related) // First sysyem.out

    for (r in related) {
        runOnUiThread {
            var elem = if (r.english != "") {
                AnimeVerticalObject(this).set(
                    r.english,
                    r.image
                ).build() // returns LinearLayout
            } else {
                AnimeVerticalObject(this).set(
                    r.title,
                    r.image
                ).build() // returns LinearLayout
            }
            println(elem) // second system.out
            relatedLayout.addView(elem!!) // Line 110

            var space = Space(this)
            space.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                10.toDp(),
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
            relatedLayout.addView(space)
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that `Int.toDp()` returns an `Int`. My log says that the view is not null as it can be seen when printed.

```
I/System.out: [Lcom.my.package.utils.AnimeResponseObject;@4f30821 
I/System.out: android.widget.LinearLayout{8ee2334 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.my.package, PID: 465
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
        at com.my.package.AnimeActivity2.onCreate$lambda-2$lambda-1(AnimeActivity2.kt:110)
        at com.my.package.AnimeActivity2.$r8$lambda$HrayXNmY3lD16wB92hio1CE3OxE(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.my.package.AnimeActivity2$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:250)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7851)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:958)
```

So now, i cannot understand why, if my view is not null (has non-null verifier), it still throws this exception. Any ideas?

Comment: `relatedLayout` is null, not `elem`.

Answer (score 1):

Your  `relatedlayout` not initialized yet and you are trying to add a view on `null` that's why you're getting this exception.

initialize  `relatedLayout` in `onCreate()` like this

```
relatedLayout=findViewById(R.id.your XML id)
```